# Android - Call Boolean Value from Another Class

Tags: java, android, boolean, return-value

If I set a value to true in one class, such as

```
static boolean mIsPremium = true;
```

I only get the correct value sometimes, as in if I use double equal signs (==) I will always return the true value.

```
if (firstClass.mIsPremium == true){
    do stuff
} else {
    do other stuff
}
```

If I only use one equal sign (=) it will return a true value, this happens when I set mIsPremium to false in the first class.

```
if (firstClass.mIsPremium = true){
    do stuff
} else {
    do other stuff
}
```

I have tried many configurations, using two = signs, using one = sign, including a new boolean in the second class that has its own value dependant upon the first boolean's value... Nothing I do seems to work correctly.

How do I call a boolean value from another class and have the value correctly used in the second class.  If it's true I want it true in the second class, if its false I want it false in the second class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are confused with the [operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

```
=
```

Is assigns the value

```
==
```

checks for the equality

```
if (firstClass.mIsPremium = true){
```

The  above line considering it as a statement and assigns the value  true to `mIsPremium`   and proceeding further.

```
if (firstClass.mIsPremium == true){
```

Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if yes then condition becomes true.

What you do is

```
if (firstClass.mIsPremium){
    do stuff
} else {
    do other stuff
}
```

Comment: I changed to 'if (firstClass.mIsPremium){...' and I do not get the correct value returned.  The original value is 'static boolean mIsPremium = true;' I expect a toast message to pop up under the if statement and nothing happens.  Why is it not returning that the value is true and showing the toast?

Also, the if statement takes place in the onCreate, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

One = sing is an assignment, an assignment in always true.

```
(a = b) #-> always true, it doesn't matter if a or b are false or true
```

Two = sing is a comparison, the result depends on what are the values of a and b.

```
(a == b) #-> true if and only if a has the same value of b
```

Answer (score 2):

Boolean can only have two values as true/false.No need to use == or =

just use

```
if (firstClass.mIsPremium)     //if mIsPremium is true
{     
    do stuff
} else {
    do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not need to use any = signs you can just do

```
if(firstClass.mIsPremium) { } // check for premium
```

or

```
if(!firstClass.mIsPremium) { } // check for not premium
```